# Solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}-y=20xe^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}-y=20xe^x$

I have found the complementary function to be $y_c=Ae^{\frac{(-2+\sqrt8)}2x}+Be^{\frac{(-2-\sqrt8)}2x}$ which doesn't seem like it should be right. Is it? Also what do I now choose as my trial to find the rest of the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. You can choose $y_p=(c_1+c_2x)e^x$.

Also you can simplify the $\frac{-2+\sqrt{8}}{2}$ to $-1+\sqrt{2}$, and $\frac{-2-\sqrt{8}}{2}$ to $-1-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: How did you know that this was the correct substitution? I attempted $cxe^x$

Comment: If there is any polynomial in the right hand side, you should try the same degree polynomial. In this case, $x$ is a first degree polynomial, so you should try $ax+b$.

Comment: I got $y=[complementary function] + 10xe^x-20e^x$ is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.